# How do I use a theme hook suggestion in template.php?

Tags: 7, theming

How do I convert a theme hook suggestion into a function in template.php?

Here is an example I pulled using TEMPLATE_preprocess_field() with dpm().

[image]

What would I name my function in template.php to utilize `field__field_video_virtual_tour__basic_drealty_listing`, and where can I find the default theme function for a text field to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default theme function for all fields is (wait for it), [`theme_field()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/theme_field/7).  You can copy this function into your own theme, and rename it to `MYTHEME_field()`, either to alter or to refer to as reference.

You would then name your specific version `MYTHEME_field__field_video_virtual_tour__basic_drealty_listing()`.  Note the two underscores separating the parts.

For reference, the standard suggestions are

- `MYTHEME_field__FIELDNAME__CONTENTTYPE()`
- `MYTHEME_field__CONTENTTYPE()`
- `MYTHEME_field__FIELDNAME()`
- `MYTHEME_field()`

Also remember, these are really just to wrap your elements with some HTML.  If you want to change the way the element itself gets rendered out, you should really make a [field formatter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/group/field_formatter/7).

Comment: You're absolutely right. A custom Field Formatter is what I was ultimately needing.  This did answer my theme override question as well though, thank you @MPD.